# Using StringUtils methods runs faster than Java methods?

Tags: java, string, apache-commons

I want to know if the methods from StringUtils from Apache Commons Lang library runs faster than Java String methods.

I know this is micro-optimization, but it's necessary because methods will be executed millions times.

Methods that using regex in Java like `split()` or String comparison with `equals()`.

Comment: So execute each a million times, and time them.

Comment: (Or at the very least, be more precise...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`StringUtils#split` is faster than `String#split`.

`String#equals` is faster than `StringUtils#equals`.

Comment: any proof in support of your answer?

Answer (score 3):

Both the methods in the Java `String` class and the methods in `StringUtils` are highly optimised for the specific tasks they were designed to solve. Different methods are designed to solve slightly different tasks. Try to pick the method that most closely matches the task you are trying to solve, and it's likely you will get very good performance.

If there are two possible approaches that look equally good, and it's vital to get every last bit of performance, then measure it! Time the performance of both approaches on your actual data.

But also remember that it's often cheaper to buy a faster computer instead of spending hours of development time micro-optimizing your code to get it to run fast on a slow machine.

Answer (score 1):

Well it probably depends on each individual method. Most of the methods represent very basic code that people often have to write by hand such as

```
return s1 == s2 || (s1 == null && s2 == null) || (s1 != null && s1.equals( s2 ) );
```

This code would very likely be optimised to the same thing by the hotspot compiler removing even the method call. I would guess that the only savings in time you'll find are in writing.

As suggested elsewhere, I would just recommend benchmarking the methods you are interesting in yourself use `System.currentTimeMillis()` around a loop that calls the method on some *random* strings; random because you don't want it optimised away.

Comment: System.nanoTime() is better for performance testing since it isn't affected by the system clock and provides times to greater precision.

Comment: Also in your example, the middle clause is unnecessary since `s1 == s2` is true if they are both null.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think it is anyhow optimized, Apache Commons contains 'helper utilities', meaning it it is more efficient for development **not for run-time performance efficiency**.

The performance may also change with **JVM used**.

I can understand, that you worry about performance with large number of executions or big data. But that does not mean that the **micro-optimization fallacy** does not apply with regards to this. It is certainly more *efficient* to spend more time thinking about and trying out other ways to improve performance of such rudimentary tasks (running not in one but in as many threads as there are CPUs on the machine, etc.). It is wiser to leave such low level stuff for the JVM. The just-in-time-compiler is usually much smarter than any developer in my experience.

If you really want to go that way, **you should test it**. it should not be that difficult and in case the performance depends on data, you might have the right one to test it with.

Comment: These are bold statements!

Answer (score 0):

First, have you set performance criteria? How much performance are you looking to gain?

Second, have you profiled your application as a whole under a realistic load? The first thing you should do is make sure that you're even working on the right part of the code.

Regardless, your question is too vague to be answered here. You need to provide more information about the data set you're working with, and also about the operations you're actually doing on the data. For example, one trick for optimizing away String.equals is to intern the String instances. You'll pay a pretty high upfront cost for creating the instances in the first place, but later the equals should return true based on `==` before it bothers to do a full comparison. You'd need to decide whether to apply this optimization based on the data set in question and what you're doing with the data.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you looking for faster?  Don't you have a performance requirement?  That will define whether you are *fast enough*.  As long as you meet the requirement, then move on to the next problem.  The question of "Which is faster?" implies you haven't tried either.  Pick one, check that your performance requirement is met, and only check the other if the requirement is not met.

Answer (score 0):

They're not in competition. `StringUtils` isn't a replacement for methods in the `String` class, it is a collection of common idioms on the next higher layer. `StringUtils` calls `String` in most cases. It can't do anything else, unless it used reflection, which it doesn't.